# When firing a weapon with the artificer infusion "Returning Weapon" via catapult, does it come back to your hand after the spell's conclusion?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, artificer, artificer-infusions

I'm playing a level 2 Artificer for a campaign with some friends. If I use the "Returning weapon" infusion on a hand-axe and shoot it out via the [*catapult* spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/catapult) (since a hand-axe weighs around 2 pounds according to the PHB) would the weapon return to my character's hand after spell conclusion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### It would not return.

Per the [UA artificer insert](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-Artificer2-2019.pdf)<sup>1</sup> (emphasis mine),

> This  magic   weapon  grants  a   +1  bonus   to  attack  and damage  rolls   made    with    it, and it returns  to  the wielder’s hand  immediately after it    is  used to  make a **ranged    attack**

The description of [*Catapult*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/catapult) reads:

> If the object would strike a creature, that creature must make a **Dexterity saving throw**.

Since you are not making a spell attack roll (ranged or otherwise), Catapult will not trigger the Returning property

---

<sup>1</sup> The UA version of this infusion matches exactly the wording of the [official version](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/erftlw/character-creation-class-artificer#ReturningWeapon) found in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*.

Answer (score 14):

### *Catapult* requires you to use an unattended item.

> Choose one object weighing 1 to 5 pounds within range that isn’t being worn or carried.

You could drop the *returning hand axe* to meet this requirement, but...

### *Returning* only functions for the item’s “wielder”

> it returns to the wielder’s hand immediately after […]

If you drop the *returning hand axe* to cast *catapult* with it, then you aren’t its wielder, and furthermore it doesn’t **have** a wielder. Therefore, we have no need to consider whether or not the effect would trigger—even if it does, it won’t do anything.

This is good, because I had written a quite-lengthy answer addressing how it is not clear, under the official rules, whether or not this effect would trigger. It almost-certainly shouldn’t, but there is *just barely* room to make a (very weak) case for it triggering. Even if it does, though, nothing happens.

Answer (score -2):

#### Yes, you can, if you multiclass into Fighter for Action Surge.

So, the text of the Returning Weapon Infusion states:

> it returns to the wielder’s hand immediately after it is used to make a ranged attack

While Catapult's targeting criteria state:

> Choose one object weighing 1 to 5 pounds within range that isn’t being worn or carried.

As a result, under normal circumstances, you wouldn't ne able to target the axe in a way that would trigger the axes ability. There is an exception, however:

If you multiclass into Fighter, you gain the ability Action Surge, which allows you to take a second Action. As a result, if your first Action was to Ready the casting of the Catapult spell, with the condition being that you had thrown your axe, you can then use your second Action to throw your axe, make an attack against the enemy, and trigger the axes returning ability. Then, before your axe actually returns, you use your Reaction to cast Catapult to launch it at an enemy; it then returns to you. If you have Extra Attack, you could then make a second attack with your axe.

Comment: I think this is a novel interpretation of the rules but I'd check with a DM before trying it because they might not let it work. This answer assumes that time passes between when an attack is made and when the weapon returns to hand. The rules are written such that the attack process is an instantaneous event. A DM with a strict interpretation of the rules might rule that the weapon's return is part of the attack and not something that can be interrupted by a reaction.

Comment: @Rykara On the other hand, this interpretation is pretty far away from an exploit. It costs a reaction (plus any currently running concentration), compared to simply catapulting some existing object on the ground. I'd probably allow more (outside of RAW) just from a rule-of-cool perspective, such as not requiring the reaction.

Comment: @NielSlater It also costs you your Action Surge, and the levels you've spent multiclassing into Fighter. I'm honestly not sure why this answer is being downvoted like this.

Comment: Might want to add a comment saying that the first attack won't actually hit the target because catapult "takes control" of the weapon immediately after it leaves your hand. Otherwise the axe would be out of range for the spell. Perhaps replace "before your axe actually returns" with "before your axe actually hits the target".